# Is there a way to call the child under this Id?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the room and i get error with my existing query, how can i make it work after getting the reference for room, how can i call or get the id encircled in the picture?
[image: The id refers to Instrutor key]

```
private void joinClass(cList ckey) {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("StudentCourseList").child(currentUser.getUid()).push();
    DatabaseReference ingDBref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Room");

    final String RoomCode=popupTitle.getText().toString();
    
    ingDBref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(data.child("courseKey").getValue().equals(RoomCode)){
                    myRef.setValue(ckey);
                    showMessage("Joined Successfully");
                    popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    popAddCourse.dismiss();
                }
                else{
                    showMessage("Please verify room code");
                    popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Answer on how to parse the snapshot below, but if that doesn't solve the problem (and in general going forward) instead of saying "i get error", please include the exact error message and stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `ingDBref` is loading all data under `Room`, the `dataSnapshot` in your `onDataChange` has all that data, including the **two** nested levels of dynamic keys. That means you also need two nested loops to get to the level of the individual courses:

```
ingDBref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i("Firebase", userSnapshot.getKey()); // 
            for(DataSnapshot data: userSnapshot.getChildren()){ // 
                if(data.child("courseKey").getValue().equals(RoomCode)){ //
```

Comment: i get this error....

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.educational.edukids.Student.Student_Dashboard$4.onDataChange(Student_Dashboard.java:165)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.educational.edukids.Student.Student_Dashboard$4.onDataChange(Student_Dashboard.java:165)

Comment: It looks like the `data` snapshot doesn't have a `courseKey` child then.

Comment: I have a courseKey, on the image i posted

Comment: I accept your answer because its working and it shows in my Firebase but i dont know why i still get this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.educational.edukids.Student.Student_Dashboard$4.onDataChange(Student_Dashboard.java:165)

Comment: Troubleshooting NullPointerExceptions is a well established task by now, so I recommend following this guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it